# how to open phone app or email on click from html content which contains phone number or email using react-native-render-html?

Tags: html, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-render-html

I have html contents coming from api, and used below code to render html.

```
<HTML
   html={this.state.htmlContent1}
   imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
 />
```

So if html content has a phone number or email then how can i open phone app or email app by clicking on them?

Comment: You need to loop through your html content and find if phoneNo or any image is present in it. It may not be helpful, but you can try.

Comment: how to find? i already thought about that but did not succeeded.

Comment: Check the pattern of the phone. It contains all numbers. For image, you can check the <img> tag and the extension

Comment: @Tej Hi Tej. I would be happy to help you, but I need to know: are the phone numbers and emails in `<a>` tags such as `<a href="tel:+33...">tel</a>` ? If that is the case, the answer is pretty simple and I will be happy to post.